# Order values according to the order of their associated values

Tags: java, graph, collections

I created a graph in JAVA which i want to process like the following :
Each node has a name and is associated with a number (a quantity which is an integer). I want to sort, by an ascending order, the quantities and get the associated order of the nodes into a list (i use a `HashMap` to associate the two), the first node  will be that of the minimum quantity.
I try with the following :

```
        while (itNodes.hasNext()){
            quatity= allQuatities.get(Integer.parseInt(itNodes.next().name));
            mapNameToSize.put(quantity,itNodes.next());
        }
        HashMap<Integer, Node> orderedResult = mapNameToSize.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
        for (int j=0;j<allQuatities.size();j++)
            listNodes.add(orderedResult.get(j));
```

Is it a good approach of good practices ? otherwise what could be a lower complexity alternative to this approach to achieve the mentioned goal ?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems perfect. Only one very small point: typing `orderedResult` as `HashMap` is a little awkward here. Either type it as `Map` to be neutral or `LinkedHashMap` to better show your intention.

Comment: Assuming that `itNodes` is an `Iterator`, calling `itNodes.next()` twice in the loop body is wrong. If you have an iterable as starting point, just use `for(Node n: source) /* loop body*/`. Otherwise, don’t be afraid to store the result of an expression into a local variable. I don’t know why so many developers prefer repeating expressions. For an expression with side effects, like `next()`, you must store the result to use it more than one time. Besides that, the approach is correct, but you can make `mapNameToSize` a `TreeMap` in the first place, eliminating the need for the second operation

Comment: I can't use a for loop because i iterate over itNodes on each recursive call

Comment: i use `nodeToAdd = itNodes.next();` once and then put nodeToAdd instead of double .next() calls